# Need time stamp in "MMM-yyyy" format in hive

Tags: datetime, hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

Could you help me to get time format in "MMM-yyyy" format from current_date in hive?

Thanks a lot in advance.

For example:

```
col1           col2
12-09-2016     SEP-2016
21-10-2017     OCT-2017
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'MMM-yyyy') 
AS currentdate from db.table_name;
```

Example:

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'MMM-yyyy')
    > AS currentdate from default.test limit 1;
OK
Jul-2017
Time taken: 0.043 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```